# Can it be proven/disproven that every set can be well-ordered to have a maximal element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Can we prove or disprove that every set can be well-ordered to have a maximal element in ZF or ZFC?

Or is it the area where different models have different answers to this?

Comment: The empty set cannot "be well-ordered to have a maximal element". $\;$

Comment: By taking the dual order, this is just the WOP and the answers all well known.

Comment: @GitGud A well-ordered set whose dual is also well-ordered is finite. Surely you don't mean to say all sets are finite in ZFC?

Comment: @ZhenLin: I'm sure that if you search hard enough, you'll come across someone who would argue that ZFC proves that infinite sets don't exist. (For example, because appealing to the "existence" of an infinite set is the same as appealing to Leprechauns and unicorns...)

Comment: @ZhenLin I meant you take a well-ordering and you reverse the order, i.e., you take the dual order. Minima become maxima in the dual order.

Comment: @GitGud : $\:$ That does not necessarily produce a well-order. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Right, I was just thinking about maxima, my bad.

Comment: This reminds me of the old illustration of nontransitive relationships with three boxers, (A, B, C), having three criteria (strength, speed, stamina) all of which are of equal value in winning the fight. A will beat B because he has better strength and speed, B will beat C because he has better speed and stamina, and C will beat A because he has better stamina and strength... a simple case where there is a clear ordering of any two members but not of the whole set.

Comment: @keshlam: That's just "Rock, paper, scissors".

Comment: True enough, but in a form that some folks find easier to accept as a real-world case. Not everything is transitive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a nonempty set $S$ and pick $x\in S$. Well order $S\backslash\{x\}$. Extend the resulting well-order to $S$ by making $x$ larger than every other element. You get a well-order with a maximum.

Answer (score 4):

If the set is empty, then it doesn't have any elements, in particular maximal elements. But that's the trivial, and uninteresting case. So let's casually chuck it aside, and assume we're talking about non-empty sets.

Of course that without the axiom of choice we cannot prove that every set can be well-ordered to begin with. So the axiom of choice is necessary here.

Assuming it, though, we have two cases:

1. The set is finite, in which case it will definitely have a maximal element in any well-order.
2. The set is infinite, in which case we can put it in bijection with many different ordinals. Many of which have maximal elements.

So the answer is indeed positive.

Comment: Case 0: The set is empty, in which case there is no well-order in which the set will have a maximal element. $\;$

Comment: True, I'll add that. Thanks.